# fragment activity starts twice on start

Tags: android, fragment

I followed this tutorial: [Link](http://www.android4devs.com/2015/01/how-to-make-material-design-sliding-tabs.html)

To make sliding tabs. Everything works as expected but one thing, it can't
seem to detect properly the current tab index/name because it apparently
runs twice on start (launching the same tab fragment twice, as if I swiped).

The code for Tab1

```
public class Tab1 extends Fragment {


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_1, container, false);

            System.out.println(getArguments()); // prints the bundle data I entered on ViewPagerAdapter

            return v;

    }


    // It is safe to access the views here, not in onCreate since it is called before onCreateView
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){

    }

}
```

ViewPageAdapter:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    CharSequence Titles[]; // This will Store the Titles of the Tabs which are Going to be passed when ViewPagerAdapter is created
    int NumbOfTabs; // Store the number of tabs, this will also be passed when the ViewPagerAdapter is created


    // Build a Constructor and assign the passed Values to appropriate values in the class
    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm,CharSequence mTitles[], int mNumbOfTabsumb) {
        super(fm);

        this.Titles     = mTitles;
        this.Titles     = mTitles;
        this.NumbOfTabs = mNumbOfTabsumb;

    }

    //This method return the fragment for the every position in the View Pager
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {



        Tab1 tab1 = new Tab1();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("cat_name", this.Titles[position].toString());
        args.putString("cat_index", "" + position);
        tab1.setArguments(args);

        return tab1;

    }

    // This method return the titles for the Tabs in the Tab Strip
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return Titles[position];
    }

    // This method return the Number of tabs for the tabs Strip

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NumbOfTabs;
    }
}
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    // Declaring Your View and Variables

    Toolbar toolbar;
    ViewPager pager;
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter;
    SlidingTabLayout tabs;
    CharSequence Titles[]= {"Nature","News", "Entertainment", "Social", "Web"};
    int Numboftabs       = 5;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Creating The Toolbar and setting it as the Toolbar for the activity
        //toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
        //setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        // Creating The ViewPagerAdapter and Passing Fragment Manager, Titles for the Tabs and Number Of Tabs.
        adapter =  new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), Titles, Numboftabs);

        // Assigning ViewPager View and setting the adapter
        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Assiging the Sliding Tab Layout View
        tabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabs.setDistributeEvenly(true); // To make the Tabs Fixed set this true, This makes the tabs Space Evenly in Available width

        // Setting Custom Color for the Scroll bar indicator of the Tab View
        tabs.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
            @Override
            public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
                return getResources().getColor(R.color.tabsScrollColor);
            }
        });

        // Setting the ViewPager For the SlidingTabsLayout
        tabs.setViewPager(pager);



    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }


}
```

SlidingTabLayout.java:

```
/**
 * To be used with ViewPager to provide a tab indicator component which give constant feedback as to
 * the user's scroll progress.
 * <p>
 * To use the component, simply add it to your view hierarchy. Then in your
 * {@link android.app.Activity} or {@link android.support.v4.app.Fragment} call
 * {@link #setViewPager(android.support.v4.view.ViewPager)} providing it the ViewPager this layout is being used for.
 * <p>
 * The colors can be customized in two ways. The first and simplest is to provide an array of colors
 * via {@link #setSelectedIndicatorColors(int...)}. The
 * alternative is via the {@link bm.testo.SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer} interface which provides you complete control over
 * which color is used for any individual position.
 * <p>
 * The views used as tabs can be customized by calling {@link #setCustomTabView(int, int)},
 * providing the layout ID of your custom layout.
 */
public class SlidingTabLayout extends HorizontalScrollView {
    /**
     * Allows complete control over the colors drawn in the tab layout. Set with
     * {@link #setCustomTabColorizer(bm.testo.SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer)}.
     */
    public interface TabColorizer {

        /**
         * @return return the color of the indicator used when {@code position} is selected.
         */
        int getIndicatorColor(int position);

    }

    private static final int TITLE_OFFSET_DIPS = 24;
    private static final int TAB_VIEW_PADDING_DIPS = 16;
    private static final int TAB_VIEW_TEXT_SIZE_SP = 12;

    private int mTitleOffset;

    private int mTabViewLayoutId;
    private int mTabViewTextViewId;
    private boolean mDistributeEvenly;

    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private SparseArray<String> mContentDescriptions = new SparseArray<String>();
    private ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener mViewPagerPageChangeListener;

    private final SlidingTabStrip mTabStrip;

    public SlidingTabLayout(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public SlidingTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public SlidingTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        // Disable the Scroll Bar
        setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        // Make sure that the Tab Strips fills this View
        setFillViewport(true);

        mTitleOffset = (int) (TITLE_OFFSET_DIPS * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);

        mTabStrip = new SlidingTabStrip(context);
        addView(mTabStrip, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    }

    /**
     * Set the custom {@link bm.testo.SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer} to be used.
     *
     * If you only require simple custmisation then you can use
     * {@link #setSelectedIndicatorColors(int...)} to achieve
     * similar effects.
     */
    public void setCustomTabColorizer(TabColorizer tabColorizer) {
        mTabStrip.setCustomTabColorizer(tabColorizer);
    }

    public void setDistributeEvenly(boolean distributeEvenly) {
        mDistributeEvenly = distributeEvenly;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the colors to be used for indicating the selected tab. These colors are treated as a
     * circular array. Providing one color will mean that all tabs are indicated with the same color.
     */
    public void setSelectedIndicatorColors(int... colors) {
        mTabStrip.setSelectedIndicatorColors(colors);
    }

    /**
     * Set the {@link android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener}. When using {@link bm.testo.SlidingTabLayout} you are
     * required to set any {@link android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener} through this method. This is so
     * that the layout can update it's scroll position correctly.
     *
     * @see android.support.v4.view.ViewPager#setOnPageChangeListener(android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener)
     */
    public void setOnPageChangeListener(ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener listener) {
        mViewPagerPageChangeListener = listener;
    }

    /**
     * Set the custom layout to be inflated for the tab views.
     *
     * @param layoutResId Layout id to be inflated
     * @param textViewId id of the {@link android.widget.TextView} in the inflated view
     */
    public void setCustomTabView(int layoutResId, int textViewId) {
        mTabViewLayoutId = layoutResId;
        mTabViewTextViewId = textViewId;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the associated view pager. Note that the assumption here is that the pager content
     * (number of tabs and tab titles) does not change after this call has been made.
     */
    public void setViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        mTabStrip.removeAllViews();

        mViewPager = viewPager;
        if (viewPager != null) {
            viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new InternalViewPagerListener());
            populateTabStrip();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create a default view to be used for tabs. This is called if a custom tab view is not set via
     * {@link #setCustomTabView(int, int)}.
     */
    protected TextView createDefaultTabView(Context context) {
        TextView textView = new TextView(context);
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, TAB_VIEW_TEXT_SIZE_SP);
        textView.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
        textView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
        getContext().getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.selectableItemBackground,
                outValue, true);
        textView.setBackgroundResource(outValue.resourceId);
        textView.setAllCaps(true);

        int padding = (int) (TAB_VIEW_PADDING_DIPS * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
        textView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);

        return textView;
    }

    private void populateTabStrip() {
        final PagerAdapter adapter = mViewPager.getAdapter();
        final OnClickListener tabClickListener = new TabClickListener();

        for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
            View tabView = null;
            TextView tabTitleView = null;

            if (mTabViewLayoutId != 0) {
                // If there is a custom tab view layout id set, try and inflate it
                tabView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(mTabViewLayoutId, mTabStrip,
                        false);
                tabTitleView = (TextView) tabView.findViewById(mTabViewTextViewId);
            }

            if (tabView == null) {
                tabView = createDefaultTabView(getContext());
            }

            if (tabTitleView == null && TextView.class.isInstance(tabView)) {
                tabTitleView = (TextView) tabView;
            }

            if (mDistributeEvenly) {
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) tabView.getLayoutParams();
                lp.width = 0;
                lp.weight = 1;
            }

            tabTitleView.setText(adapter.getPageTitle(i));
            tabView.setOnClickListener(tabClickListener);
            String desc = mContentDescriptions.get(i, null);
            if (desc != null) {
                tabView.setContentDescription(desc);
            }

            mTabStrip.addView(tabView);
            if (i == mViewPager.getCurrentItem()) {
                tabView.setSelected(true);
            }

            tabTitleView.setTextColor(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.selector));
            tabTitleView.setTextSize(14);
            tabTitleView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
        }
    }

    public void setContentDescription(int i, String desc) {
        mContentDescriptions.put(i, desc);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();

        if (mViewPager != null) {
            scrollToTab(mViewPager.getCurrentItem(), 0);
        }
    }

    private void scrollToTab(int tabIndex, int positionOffset) {
        final int tabStripChildCount = mTabStrip.getChildCount();
        if (tabStripChildCount == 0 || tabIndex < 0 || tabIndex >= tabStripChildCount) {
            return;
        }

        View selectedChild = mTabStrip.getChildAt(tabIndex);
        if (selectedChild != null) {
            int targetScrollX = selectedChild.getLeft() + positionOffset;

            if (tabIndex > 0 || positionOffset > 0) {
                // If we're not at the first child and are mid-scroll, make sure we obey the offset
                targetScrollX -= mTitleOffset;
            }

            scrollTo(targetScrollX, 0);
        }
    }

    private class InternalViewPagerListener implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
        private int mScrollState;

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            int tabStripChildCount = mTabStrip.getChildCount();
            if ((tabStripChildCount == 0) || (position < 0) || (position >= tabStripChildCount)) {
                return;
            }

            mTabStrip.onViewPagerPageChanged(position, positionOffset);

            View selectedTitle = mTabStrip.getChildAt(position);
            int extraOffset = (selectedTitle != null)
                    ? (int) (positionOffset * selectedTitle.getWidth())
                    : 0;
            scrollToTab(position, extraOffset);

            if (mViewPagerPageChangeListener != null) {
                mViewPagerPageChangeListener.onPageScrolled(position, positionOffset,
                        positionOffsetPixels);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            mScrollState = state;

            if (mViewPagerPageChangeListener != null) {
                mViewPagerPageChangeListener.onPageScrollStateChanged(state);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            if (mScrollState == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                mTabStrip.onViewPagerPageChanged(position, 0f);
                scrollToTab(position, 0);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < mTabStrip.getChildCount(); i++) {
                mTabStrip.getChildAt(i).setSelected(position == i);
            }
            if (mViewPagerPageChangeListener != null) {
                mViewPagerPageChangeListener.onPageSelected(position);
            }
        }

    }

    private class TabClickListener implements OnClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            for (int i = 0; i < mTabStrip.getChildCount(); i++) {
                if (v == mTabStrip.getChildAt(i)) {
                    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

SlidingTabStrip:

```
class SlidingTabStrip extends LinearLayout {

    private static final int DEFAULT_BOTTOM_BORDER_THICKNESS_DIPS = 0;
    private static final byte DEFAULT_BOTTOM_BORDER_COLOR_ALPHA = 0x26;
    private static final int SELECTED_INDICATOR_THICKNESS_DIPS = 3;
    private static final int DEFAULT_SELECTED_INDICATOR_COLOR = 0xFF33B5E5;

    private final int mBottomBorderThickness;
    private final Paint mBottomBorderPaint;

    private final int mSelectedIndicatorThickness;
    private final Paint mSelectedIndicatorPaint;

    private int mSelectedPosition;
    private float mSelectionOffset;

    private SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer mCustomTabColorizer;
    private final SimpleTabColorizer mDefaultTabColorizer;

    SlidingTabStrip(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    SlidingTabStrip(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setWillNotDraw(false);

        final float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

        TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
        context.getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.colorForeground, outValue, true);
        final int themeForegroundColor =  outValue.data;

        int defaultBottomBorderColor = setColorAlpha(themeForegroundColor,
                DEFAULT_BOTTOM_BORDER_COLOR_ALPHA);

        mDefaultTabColorizer = new SimpleTabColorizer();
        mDefaultTabColorizer.setIndicatorColors(DEFAULT_SELECTED_INDICATOR_COLOR);

        mBottomBorderThickness = (int) (DEFAULT_BOTTOM_BORDER_THICKNESS_DIPS * density);
        mBottomBorderPaint = new Paint();
        mBottomBorderPaint.setColor(defaultBottomBorderColor);

        mSelectedIndicatorThickness = (int) (SELECTED_INDICATOR_THICKNESS_DIPS * density);
        mSelectedIndicatorPaint = new Paint();
    }

    void setCustomTabColorizer(SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer customTabColorizer) {
        mCustomTabColorizer = customTabColorizer;
        invalidate();
    }

    void setSelectedIndicatorColors(int... colors) {
        // Make sure that the custom colorizer is removed
        mCustomTabColorizer = null;
        mDefaultTabColorizer.setIndicatorColors(colors);
        invalidate();
    }

    void onViewPagerPageChanged(int position, float positionOffset) {
        mSelectedPosition = position;
        mSelectionOffset = positionOffset;
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        final int height = getHeight();
        final int childCount = getChildCount();
        final SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer tabColorizer = mCustomTabColorizer != null
                ? mCustomTabColorizer
                : mDefaultTabColorizer;

        // Thick colored underline below the current selection
        if (childCount > 0) {
            View selectedTitle = getChildAt(mSelectedPosition);
            int left = selectedTitle.getLeft();
            int right = selectedTitle.getRight();
            int color = tabColorizer.getIndicatorColor(mSelectedPosition);

            if (mSelectionOffset > 0f && mSelectedPosition < (getChildCount() - 1)) {
                int nextColor = tabColorizer.getIndicatorColor(mSelectedPosition + 1);
                if (color != nextColor) {
                    color = blendColors(nextColor, color, mSelectionOffset);
                }

                // Draw the selection partway between the tabs
                View nextTitle = getChildAt(mSelectedPosition + 1);
                left = (int) (mSelectionOffset * nextTitle.getLeft() +
                        (1.0f - mSelectionOffset) * left);
                right = (int) (mSelectionOffset * nextTitle.getRight() +
                        (1.0f - mSelectionOffset) * right);
            }

            mSelectedIndicatorPaint.setColor(color);

            canvas.drawRect(left, height - mSelectedIndicatorThickness, right,
                    height, mSelectedIndicatorPaint);
        }

        // Thin underline along the entire bottom edge
        canvas.drawRect(0, height - mBottomBorderThickness, getWidth(), height, mBottomBorderPaint);
    }

    /**
     * Set the alpha value of the {@code color} to be the given {@code alpha} value.
     */
    private static int setColorAlpha(int color, byte alpha) {
        return Color.argb(alpha, Color.red(color), Color.green(color), Color.blue(color));
    }

    /**
     * Blend {@code color1} and {@code color2} using the given ratio.
     *
     * @param ratio of which to blend. 1.0 will return {@code color1}, 0.5 will give an even blend,
     *              0.0 will return {@code color2}.
     */
    private static int blendColors(int color1, int color2, float ratio) {
        final float inverseRation = 1f - ratio;
        float r = (Color.red(color1) * ratio) + (Color.red(color2) * inverseRation);
        float g = (Color.green(color1) * ratio) + (Color.green(color2) * inverseRation);
        float b = (Color.blue(color1) * ratio) + (Color.blue(color2) * inverseRation);
        return Color.rgb((int) r, (int) g, (int) b);
    }

    private static class SimpleTabColorizer implements SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer {
        private int[] mIndicatorColors;

        @Override
        public final int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
            return mIndicatorColors[position % mIndicatorColors.length];
        }

        void setIndicatorColors(int... colors) {
            mIndicatorColors = colors;
        }
    }
}
```

Once the application starts The Tab1 Code runs Twice because
this line is printed twice. Once for the 0th element and once
for the 1st element. Even though the active tab is still the first.
When I swipe to the next tab it displays the third tabs name/index
meaning It's one number ahead.

```
System.out.println(getArguments());
```

I tried checking if savedBundleInstance is null and add
a return statement if it isn't but nothing changed. I'm not
sure what else to try because I'm a bit new to fragments and sliding tabs.

Update:
To explain a bit better. Once the app starts I see the println(getArguments) print twice. First time it displays
"Nature" (index 0), then it displays the second title "News" (index 1).
Previously declared as tab names on

```
CharSequence Titles[]= {"Nature","News", "Entertainment"....
```

But the active tab is still "Nature".
The funny thing is that when I swipe to the next tab, to open "News", the second element it prints item with index 2, meaning "Entertainment", and so on.

This is my console on launch:

```
I/System.out﹕ Bundle[{cat_name=Nature, cat_index=0}]
I/System.out﹕ Bundle[{cat_name=News, cat_index=1}]
```